# Synchronize access to particular indexes in int array

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I use the int array.

I use that method to fill indexes in array.

```
public void makeSelectionOfGivenNumber(int number) throws InterruptedException 
{
    if (this.table[number]!= 0) 
    {
        int multiple;
        multiple = number + number;

        while (multiple <= upperRange) 
        {
            this.table[multiple] = 0;
            multiple += number;
        }
    }
}
```

For example, one thread starts from 2 and eliminates all multiples, a second thread starts from 5 and makes the same activities. In some case the simultaneously the value in index 10 (in both cases are multiples). How to use in this case semaphores or other tools to lock that only one thread has access on particular index, not the whole array. I want that these two threads would work in parallel on the same table.

Comment: `AtomicIntegerArray` might be enough for this.

Comment: @Bubletan, using AtomicIntegerArray and method set(index,value) -> only one thread at once on specific index can modify value?

Comment: Well, it doesn't lock, but it guarantees that changes are immediately visible to other threads.

Comment: @Bubletan All right, but when one thread starts from 2 and second starts from 3, can it be conflict for example on 6 index, when they both at the same time try to write cell on that index? Can AtomicIntergerArray exclude this situation?

Comment: Using table.compareAndSet method can resolve the access to the same index in array by two threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You need to create an additional array of locks (ReadWriteLock, a dimension of the array is how you want) and before each attempt to read/change in the target array to take a lock on reading or on writing the element into the array. To take the lock need to calculate an index from the required index of target array and the capacity of the additional array.

Maybe I'm not quite correctly understood the task

```
public class SomeTask {

    private final ReadWriteLock[] locks = locks(5);
    private int[] table;
    private int upperRange;

    public SomeTask(int[] table, int upperRange) {
        this.table = table;
        this.upperRange = upperRange;
    }

    public void makeSelectionOfGivenNumber(int number) {
        if (this.table[number] != 0) {
            int multiple;
            multiple = number + number;
            while (multiple <= upperRange) {
                ReadWriteLock lock = getLock(multiple);
                try {
                    lock.writeLock().lock();
                    this.table[multiple] = 0;
                } finally {
                    lock.writeLock().unlock();
                }
                multiple += number;
            }
        }
    }

    private ReadWriteLock getLock(int number) {
        return locks[(locks.length - 1) & number];
    }

    private ReadWriteLock[] locks(int size) {
        ReadWriteLock[] result = new ReadWriteLock[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            result[i] = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: can you give some example of this?

Comment: Since you are only locking when you write, the first read access to `this.table[number] != 0` is not synchronized, and you may not be able to see the value written to that index by another thread.

Comment: @segabriel, your solution works fine. How about performance, I have checked times using difference Syste.nanoTime between start and end. It looks poor using threads in this case towards sequence task. Is it possible to boost it?

Comment: This task is connected with Erastotenes Sieve. Problem is when one thread starts from 2 and second thread starts from 5, it can possible that they gain acccess to cell of number 10 at the same time. However finally it will be there 0, but it is not correct if we talk about paraller programm.

Comment: @maciejka performance - maybe should add following check
`if (this.table[multiple] != 0)`
before try to get lock in the loop